# How can I run code on a route change from certain pages using react-router 5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've found lots of examples on v4 with the `onLeave` function. it seems this was discontinued after v4 however.

I've seen some `<Prompt>` examples but dont think thats what i'm looking for. if you have a case that will work i am open to it.

My Scenario:
React v16 app where i have multiple tables. I have a section in the store (global state) where i retain certain ui preferences. the tables paginate and reuse some of the same state info for pagination, sort, etc.

user story - user selects page 4, then navigates to another table, is still on page 4 (pagination is read from the store). I simple want to purge the values from state (im using redux so i will call an action to do this) but how can i trigger that, for example, on only a few routes in my app. this way i can reset it on leave and its ready by the time the user gets to the next table?

```
//edit for comment 1, basic example
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/one-thing",
    component: OneThing,
  },
  {
    path: "/two-thing",
    component: TwoThing,
  }, 
...
```

this is a huge app, but this might clarify. How can i run code, when i leave the path `/one-thing`?

we used to be able to do this in v4

```
  {
    path: "/two-thing",
    component: TwoThing,
    onLeave: doAThing,
  },
```

Comment: Is the new table on a new route? or is it on the same route with a different table? Can you share a example code snippet?

Comment: It's not much clearer. On one hand you say the user story is that they are still on page 4 after accessing/navigating to another table, but below you explicitly ask about running code when you leave a path "/one-thing".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you could either listen for changes to the current location via the `history` object in a parent component.

[history.listen](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener)

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from "react";

...

const history = useHistory();

useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
    console.log('Route changed', { location, action });
    // Apply route change logic, i.e. dispatch to store
  });
  return unlisten;
}, []);
```

Or use unmounting `useEffect` cleanup function in the component with table.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

...

useEffect(() => {
  return() => {
    // component unmounting (maybe from route change)
    // Apply route change logic, i.e. dispatch to store
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: oooooh, thanks Drew. the cleanup function on the useEffect hook looks like it might work on the local components. i'll try that.